# How to locate icon inside bootstrap 4 input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap 4 input field:

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
</div>
```

And the result of this code is:
[image]

the question is how can I move the check icon to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the background position of `form-control-success`...

```
.form-control-success {
    background-position: center left .5625rem;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/SeJ4SykNxW

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap class that creates the position of the feedback message is

```
div.form-control-feedback
```

The basics of this class according to bootstrap is the following:

```
.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

So what you could do is add the following to your CSS

```
.form-control-feedback {
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

if this doesn't work try adding `!important;` to overrule the bootstrap class generated `CSS`.

You could also try:

```
.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 200;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Changing the right position as above is not the best solution but it is a second solution for if `left: 0;` doesn't work.

Hope this helps!